# Добавить репозиторий другой учетной записи

Tags: git, github

У меня есть две уч. записи на гитхабе. Я как-то так сделал, что у первой на самом деле всего одна репо, но на главной странице https://github.com/ отображаются ещё 2 репо второй учётки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас мне нужно добавить ещё один репозиторий из второй учётки, что бы так же отображался pantusru/repo, но я не могу вспомнить как я это делал, подскажите. Знаю, что это точно было не через форк.

Comment: через настройки репозитория можно добавить collaborator

Comment: Точно, помогло! спасибо.